# Некорректно работает датапикер

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla

Добрый день! Проблема в том что я вывел datepicker, но при первом клике он выбирает сразу две даты, текущую и ту что была выбрана. Как убрать данную проблему, подскажите, пожалуйста.

```
jQuery('#date_range').datepicker({
   minDate: '+0',
   changeMonth: true,
   changeYear: true,
   numberOfMonths: 3,
   range: 'multiple', // режим - выбор нескольких дат
   dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy",
   range_multiple_max: '25', // макимальное число выбираемых дат
   onSelect: function(dateText, inst, extensionRange) {
       // extensionRange - объект расширения
      jQuery('input[name=multipleDate]').val(extensionRange.datesText.join(','));
}
```

Comment: ну, отключите мультипле - будет выбирать только одну дату

Comment: Мне надо что бы он выбирал не одну дату. Тут проблема в том что только при первом клике(при одном клике) он добавляет сразу две даты, а не одну. Дальше все нормально.

Answer (score 0):

В общем разобрался как исправить. Если кто столкнется с данной проблемой вот рабочая версия:

```
jQuery('#date').datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                setDate: null,
                changeYear: true,
                numberOfMonths: 3,
                range: 'multiple', // режим - выбор нескольких дат
                dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy",
                minDate: "+0d",
                onSelect: function(dateText, inst, extensionRange) {
                    // extensionRange - объект расширения
                    jQuery('input[name=dates]').val(extensionRange.datesText.join(','));
                }
            });

            var extensionRange = jQuery('#date').datepicker('widget').data('datepickerExtensionRange');
            if (extensionRange.datesText)
                extensionRange.datesText = [];
```